# Why AngularJs doesn't always load data?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5.4

I am loading data to `$scope` but it doesn't always load. I am getting sometimes when I refresh an error

```
GET http://localhost/allClients 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And sometimes it works. I can't my hand on why this happen.

I have my code in Angular like this:

```
$http.get('allClients')
    .then(function(res){
       $scope.clients = res.data;
});
```

My server side is Laravel 5.4

**EDIT:**
Query on laravel

```
public function allClients(){

    $system_id = env('SYSTEM_ID');

    return DB::select("SELECT 
                            client.*
                       FROM 
                            client 
                        WHERE 
                            system_id = $system_id") ;
 }
```

Comment: Its a server side error and I don't think `angular` has to do anything with this..

Comment: Check the error on server. Its a server error. Try hitting the url directly in browser. You should still get the same error.

Comment: I have notice that laravl have problom sometimes with env variables that cause the problom. I have edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation of Angular:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Your API call returns Internal Server Error, so $http runs errorCallback